# Python passing dictionary to process in multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, arguments

I have a class that contains a (large) number of different properties, including a few dictionaries.  When I pass an instance of the class through to a new process, all of the numeric values seem to get passed in correctly, but any dictionaries that were in the class object get emptied.

Here's a simple test I cooked up that demonstrates my problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class State:
    a = 0
    b = {}

def f(s, i):
    print "f:", s.a, s.b

def main():

    state = State()

    state.a = 11
    state.b['testing'] = 12

    print "Main:", state.a, state.b

    ps = []
    for i in range(1):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(state, i))
        p.start()           # Do the work
        ps.append(p)
    for p in ps:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the output to be

```
Main: 11 {'testing': 12}
f: 11 {'testing': 12}
```

but instead I get

```
Main: 11 {'testing': 12}
f: 11 {}
```

Comment: I get your expected output when I test your example.

Comment: wait what?  I'm using Python 2.6.6 on Windows 7, you?  :(

Comment: Works with 2.6.6 as well for me. Perhaps a Windows issue?

Comment: it probably is a windows issue. I get the same thing as @numegil while running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7

Comment: Same thing with windows. Are you sure you mean for these to be class variables instead of instance variables? There's probably some issue sending the pickled dictionary for some reason.

Comment: Good 'ol Windows.  Ah well, solved via a workaround (passing in the dictionaries in addition to the State object, then setting them first thing in the child function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this problem by passing the dictionaries in explicitly in addition to the state.  e.g.

`p = Process(target=f, args=(state, i, state.b))`

Answer (score 4):

the problem is clearly described in the documentation for the multiprocessing module: windows lacks a `fork()` system call, so on windows, the module source code gets reevaluated at the start of each process, thus the current state is not preserved. (on un*x based system, including OSX, Process is implemented using a fork, and the state is preserved)

note that i am talking about the state of the whole python module.

your way of holding a state is wrong: the `a` and `b` members of the `State` class are class-wide 'static' members, they are not part of an instance of a `State` object. when doing `state.a = 11`, you are modifying the `State` class, not an instance of the class.

your code would have worked fine if `a` and `b` had been instance members of the `State` class:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.a = 0
        self.b = {}
```

then, passing the `state` instance to a new Process, would have correctly passed the value as expected.

Comment: I posted a question here regarding the class variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77824427/python-class-variable-not-updated-when-passed-to-new-process