# Python apply_async passing a dict in args

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am having a problem passing a dict through `multiprocessing.poll.apply_async` to the child processing.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores) #Create a pool of workers, one for each core
for job in range(cores): #Prep to assign each core a job
    pool.apply_async(initialize, args=(job,z,w,floor,p,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

w is an object with the `.neighbors` attribute.  This attribute is a `dict` that stores the topology of the id, (i.e. it's neighbors).  When I attempt to access this attribute in a child process I return an empty `dict`.  When I attempt to pass the dict in directly, I return an empty `dict`:

```
neighbor_dict = w.neighbors
...
pool.apply_async(initialize, args=(job,z,w,neighbor_dict,floor,p,))
```

I do not think that I need to use a manager to gain access to the dict because I am never writing to it; I only need read access.

Also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353973/python-passing-dictionary-to-process-in-multiprocessing) is similar in that the OP is using multiprocessing.  In contrast to using pool they are using Process.  I am on a POSIX system as well, so should be impacted by fork().

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It appears to not be possible to pass a class instance, from another module, through.  While `print w.neighbors` was returning a `dict`, `type(w.neighbors)` was a class instance.  Conversion to a `dict` solved the issue.