# python class variable not updated when passed to new Process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, static-members, class-variables

Why doesn't a new Process get the updated class attr value (in Windows btw). (It's the same if the attr was just a str). I'm guessing the 3rd case worked because assignment gave it a *instance* attr.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525883/1582790 This post says something about the static/class members but didn't explain why. (The bit about setting the class member using `instance.attr=` seems incorrect as seen in my third case)

```
class A:
    a1 = {}

def fp(a):
    print(a.a1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    A.a1.update({"p":"1"}) # update class var
    p1 = Process(target=fp, args=(a,))
    p1.start()

    A.a1 = {"p":"2"}
    # print('--', a.a1) # {'p': '2'}
    p2 = Process(target=fp, args=(a,))
    p2.start()

    a.a1 = {"p":"3"} # doesn't change A.a1
    # print('--', A.a1) # {'p': '2'}
    p3 = Process(target=fp, args=(a,))
    p3.start()
```

prints:

```
{}
{}
{'p': '3'}
```

Comment: It's unclear why you think that the upvoted answer in the linked question "didn't explain why", when it clearly explains, "windows lacks a `fork()` system call, so on windows, the module source code gets reevaluated at the start of each process, thus the current state is not preserved."

Comment: sorry im noob, but i guess i understand now. everything is moot besides the args passed to the process?

Comment: Yes, because the module is reloaded with the [spawn method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) on Windows. You simply have to pass all necessary values as arguments to child processes.

Comment: yea i understood that. i just didn't think class members are not part of the object. thanks!